# How to make a distinction Java Input Type?

Tags: java

I'm not a programmer, I'm a tester. But sometimes I write code.
I want a function or class that separates input type on its own.
I couldn't do that with construction. 
The flowchart is below.
May you lead?

https://ibb.co/C5LLkwc

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-for-free site. If you say you couldn't do it, it sounds like you have at least tried something: please show your attempt(s).

Comment: i just want the lead not all the codes, i couldnt find how i search at all. thanks

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners, since we have no way of knowing if it points to something that's NSFW. If you want to include images in your question, there's an "embed image" option in the toolbar.

Comment: okey i'll keep it in my mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    getType(5);

}
private static void getType(Object input)
{
    if(input instanceof String){
        /// code
    }
    else if(input instanceof Integer)
    {
        ///code
    }
    else {
        ///code
    }

}
```